# overriding percentage font-size attribute from html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple webpage where opening `html` tag has an attribute `font-size:60% !important` set in css file.

```
<html>
<head>
... some js and css ...
</head>
<body>
... header ...
... content ... <-- need to replace that by new content
... footer ...
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is rendered well (header/content/footer).

I also have another file where I've got content to be placed on this webpage (based on bootstrap 4) and I am not allowed to modify existing js/css files (they are loaded via API, so created dynamically).

Problem is that this content looks well when I render it it in separated file as it is. Once I replace old content with new (leave header and footer) and add css files it looks well but of course everything is smaller due to this font-size set in html tag.

Is there any way to make it working?
I've tried to unset current font size by `font-size:unset` also in html tag (by adding and targeting class) and then my content is rendered properly but unfortunately header and footer have to big font then.
Looks like the best way would be to unset this font-size only for this new content which can be enclosed in a div but I didn't found a way to do that.

Here is a jsfiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfc4my3L/7/)
It basicaly shows my problem, html tag styling is loaded with external js API and cannot do anything with that.

I am backend programmer so do not have much experience with all css stuff. Need help with that...

Answer (score 1):

If you can add all your new content in a div, as you say, and then add a class to that div like:

```html
<div class="content">…</div>
```

Then your css to set the font size would be:

```css
html .content {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Now for your specific problem:

- Say the font-size was 100px (as an example);
- the font-size set on `<HTML>` is 62.5%, so 62.5px;
- The font-size for the content wants to be back to 100px, and %'s are relative, so if you do 100% on the `<content>` you get (100% * 62.5px = 62.5px);
- You need your content bigger, and this works out to be (1 / 0.625 = 1.6x, or 160%)
- I believe your solution is then to set css of:

```css
html .content {
  font-size: 160%;
}
```

You should not need the `!important` flag for this to work.

Comment: Or a `span` instead of `div` as required.

Comment: I've added fiddle to my question so it shows my problem better. Unfortunately this solution do not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
font-size: 137.5% !important;/*62.5% = 100% - 37.5% so 137.5% will be original font size*/
}
```

Comment: I've added fiddle to my question so it shows my problem better.