# Increase font-size for whole div content (bootstrap - using rem) while root html tag font-size set

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Have big problem with following:

Need to merge two templates: one standard template with general look (header and footer) created before and used on some "sister" sites so they look similiar and another new one prepared based on bootstrap 4 with content only (no header and footer).

Let's assume standard font size is 16px.
Html tag has a styling changing it to 10px. (62.5%)
Header and footer use pure css for styling and rem units.
Content div use bootstrap 4 which is also using rems for styling, but this content was prepared using standard 100% size, so 16px, not 10px.

Due to that content div is smaller than it was planned and looks badly, while header and footer looks very well.
When I will unset html root element font sizing by `font-size:unset !important;` then content looks well while header and footer too big.

Cannot change old template with this html tag font sizing - it is generated by external JS.

```
<html lang="en" style="font-size: 62.5% !important;">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap4.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      Header (using rem for sizing, no bootstrap)
    </div>

    <div class="content"> <!--  (using bootstrap, so rem for sizing) -->
      Content
      <h2>
        H1 here
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div>
      Footer (using rem for sizing, no bootstrap)
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make content div size to calculate size using 16px not 10px or something?
Was trying to achieve that for a whole day with ccs or js, but still no result..

Comment: `<div class="content" style="font-size:100%;">`

Comment: Posting the same question three times on subsequent days  (https://stackoverflow.com/q/64876358/5641669 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/64861841/5641669) won't bring you a better result...

Comment: They are very similiar but not the same. I found out more details while digging deeper into this problem. If i just change previous one than anwears will not małe sense any longer.

Comment: @john Smith that will not work as font will still be 10px. Making it 160% will result in 16px then if not definig size in content div with rem but em for ex. Once I use rem then it will be still calculated from htmls 10px...